# custom attachment field in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, attachment

i need to alter the default behaviour of sharepoint attachment in such a way that when user click 'attach file' the "partAttachment" span get visible which asks user to upload a file.

i want to add another filed of "Title" i.e. the title of the file being uploaded, in the partAttachment span. by doing this i want that sharepoint stores filepath , as it alread does, and title of the file as well. and in the end i want this titile to be stored where sharepoint stores the file path and i should be able to retrive the paths and title when needed. can y ou plz suggest smething.

i already tried to make a custom field using upload control that take title and file from the user but cant understand where to upload the file as it normaly does with default upload system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a right trail. Try using the Attachments collection of list item.
smth like

```
mySpListitem.Attachments.Add(fileName, fileBytes);
```

then use your own field rendering control to display the attached files in the way you want. 
In order to retrieve an attachment for an item you should create a link that points to {ListUrl}/Attachments/{ItemId}/{Filename}

for example http://.../Lists/Tasks/Attachments/1/Devices%202.png

Comment: ok now what i have is something like image below

http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/9859/54642888.jpg


Problem is that when i press add button i put the title and paths in a grid as string but how to put the file itself as an attachment to the current item being inserted. 

you suggested to do

mySpListitem.Attachments.Add(fileName, fileBytes);


do u mean that i get the refrence of list 'mySpListitem' and do put the above statment in click event of add button ????

Comment: kind of. since you have your own field you should have a control for you field to render. this control should inherit from BaseFieldControl. and this way your control will have a property Item that reflects the currently edited item. refer to this item's property called Attachments to store and grab your files from.

Comment: i came up with the foloowing code
`code`
                SPListItem itemm;
                itemm = this.ListItem;
                SPAttachmentCollection attachments = itemm.Attachments;
                attachments.Add(txtFileTitle.Text, [fileinbytes]);
`code`
what you say ?
i cant see the output due to some other errors. but do you think this wil work ?